# sonar / git see all committers

Tags: git, version-control, sonarqube

Joined a project and i need to review code of 6 developers. There have been a lot of developers in the last 2 years. Ran sonar with scm plug in but the top 10 don't include my developers.

1. How can i get list of all developers from Sonar SCM (Sql or thru the web ui - its all on my local)? OR
2. Can I get a list of all unique committers via git?

Anyway is fine... then I will add to my sonar script to ignore all but the 6. Note I dont want authors but committers and stats and diffs on files ever committed by them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the names of all the committers directly from Git and pipe them through `sort` to filter out duplicates:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%cn" | sort -u
```

`%cn` is the committer name. See `git help log`'s *Pretty formats* section for more options (e.g. including email addresses).